# GIT Controlled Access

Tags: git, apache, gitolite

I have set up the apache server and my git repository resides in it. How can I allow my developers to have read and write options and limit others for read only. Platform is windows 7. I was working with gitolite but couldn't succeed with it.

Comment: This... ehmm... looks contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider [gitblit](http://gitblit.com/): its [features](http://gitblit.com/features.html) include ACL (Access control Level)

And since it is a pure Java stack for managing, viewing, and serving Git repositories, you can easily install it on Windows.